# C++ and SDL 2 - Creating a constants-only header: undefined reference to Constants::window

Tags: c++, sdl-2

So I started a free time game project with C++ and SDL 2 and ran into a puzzling problem.

I have a header file where I intend to store globally used data.

```
class Constants {
public:
    static SDL_Window* window;

    const static int w = 640;
    const static int h = 480;
};
```

Now when I reference the window elsewhere, an "undefined reference" error comes up. I've tried adding a null definition before the main function, but it still does not work.

So the problem comes up here:

```
SDLManager::SDLManager() {

    // ......

    // THIS BREAKS
    Constants::window = SDL_CreateWindow("Caption", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        Constants::w, Constants::h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
}
```

What's wrong and what can I do about it? I've coded successfully with SDL 1 before.

Comment: You may want to clarify if you are using C++11 or not, just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced similar problems during my own game development (though I used Allegro)

What you need to do is define the variable/class in question. You have only declared it. You now need to define it.

```
// constants.h
class Constants {
    public:
    static SDL_Window* window;

    const static int w = 640;
    const static int h = 480;
};

// constants.cpp
#include "constants.h"

Constants::SDL_Window *window;
```

I would love to be corrected if if I'm a little off in my syntax though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!
The definition is SDL_Window* Constants::window.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you will need to forward declare the SDL_Window class in your header.

Also, if the above is a linker error, you will need to let the compiler know what library to link with and where to find it.